# Mapping a script over all lines of stdin

Tags: bash

Is there a more idiomatic way of doing the following:

`cat some_lines.txt | while read x; do ./process_line.sh $x; done`

ie. applying a script to each line of stdin?

I could include the `while read x;` boilerplate in the script itself, but that doesn't really feel right either.

Comment: Running a subprocess (as when spawning a new shell to process a single line of input) is a fairly expensive operation -- a `fork()`, an `exec()`, etc. Generally, you'll want each `process_line` invocation to handle as many lines as possible just for performance reasons, assuming it can be written efficiently enough to not be spawning a bunch of subprocesses per line of input in turn.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm not used to thinking in terms of subprocesses, when using eg. a `map` construct in Clojure. So I guess the answer is to do the `while read x` dance in the script itself?

Comment: Gotcha. Shell is a very different language -- spinning things up is expensive. `foo | bar | baz | qux` is cheap from the shell's perspective if you run it once and pipe thousands or millions of lines through that one instance, but hideously expensive if you run it once per line processed in a loop, since it forks off four subprocesses with FIFOs attaching them and then has to clean that whole thing up afterwards.

Comment: (similarly, `cat some_lines.txt | ...` is actually incurring a performance penalty *in and of itself*: you're forking off a subshell which then `exec`s a copy of `/bin/cat`, and then the right-hand side of the pipeline can only read a FIFO with the output of that copy of `/bin/cat` rather than directly from `some_lines.txt`)

Comment: ...that's especially important if the thing you're running is a program like `sort` which can parallelize if given a seekable file handle (so each subprocess can handle a different chunk of the file, with results then merge-sorted together) -- give it a FIFO and it can *only* read front-to-back, creating a single-process bottleneck.

Comment: ...and btw, `while read x` actually has some bugs in and of itself -- as given, it mangles literal backslashes and removes leading and trailing whitespace. Use `while IFS= read -r x; do ./process_line "$line"; done` if you don't want those behaviors.

Comment: That's pretty enlightening! I'm still a few steps away from idiomatic bash!

Comment: (along the same lines, see [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) re: consequences of piping from `cat` into a `while read` loop).

Comment: (...and btw, if you're writing shell scripts that *do* a lot of `while read` loops or such, consider ksh93 instead of bash -- it's a fair bit snappier at runtime).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running an external process and have GNU `xargs`, consider:

```
xargs -n1 -d $'\n' ./process_line.sh <some_lines.txt
```

If you don't like the `while read` loop's verbosity, and are running a shell function (where a `fork()` isn't natively needed, and thus where using an external tool like `xargs` or GNU parallel has a substantial performance cost), you can avoid it by wrapping the loop in a function:

```
for_each_line() {
  local line
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    "$@" "$line" </dev/null
  done
}
```

...can be run as:

```
process_line() {
  echo "Processing line: $1"
}
for_each_line process_line <some_lines.txt
```

Comment: It still feels very verbose, if I'm piping through several scripts?

Comment: "Piping through several scripts"? Do you mean in the context of a pipeline, where the first script's output is input to the second, or in some other context?

Comment: Moving away from individual scripts to functions seems like the right direction in my case!

Answer (score 0):

GNU Parallel is made for this kind of tasks - provided there is no problem in running the processing in parallel:

```
cat some_lines.txt | parallel ./process_line.sh {}
```

By default it will run one job per cpu-core. This can be adjusted with `--jobs`.

There is an overhead of running it through GNU Parallel in the order of 5 ms per job. One of the benefits you get is that you are guaranteed the output from the different jobs are not jumbled together and you can therefore use use the output as if the jobs had not been run in parallel:

```
cat some_lines.txt | parallel ./process_line.sh {} | do_post_processing
```

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

For security reasons you should install GNU Parallel with your package manager, but if GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
(wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel